# How to find out if some videos of many are corrupt?

Tags: mp4, file-corruption

**My question is:**
Are there any ways to "scan" a library for corrupted files, so that I can delete or fix them?

I have a *plex mediaserver* running, but when I wanted to see one of my series it had a corrupted episode.

I have over 400 videos, so it would be hard to manually search for corrupted files.
BTW I am using *Handbrake* to compress videos.